# Can't locate JDK x64 in intellijIDEA

Tags: java, configuration, intellij-idea

I am starting a new project, and the client requires us to work in IntelliJIdea. I installed it and tried to do the ant build. It turns our I need 64 bit jdk for the build. So I installed it. Now, however I need to configure it in IntelliJIdea. Here is the message I get:

> JDK (1.6_x64) needed to run this ANT target is not configured. Please
>   update your settings in the Project | Libraries menu.

Can somebody help me locate this `Project | Libraries menu` menu please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press ctrl+alt+shift+s, and on the left hand side you'll see Project Settings -> Libraries.

Comment: Thank you! That got me one step further! However, how do I add the jdk here?

Comment: hmmm for project JDK you'd usually add it under `Project Settings | Modules | Dependencies | Module SDK`. If you'd like to add it under libraries, press the `+` button on the top and select `Java`.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: Where do I configure project JDK?
>
> A: In the Project Settings dialog.
>
> To add a JDK to project, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S, under Platform
>   Settings click JDKs and specify JDK path. After that, you can click
>   Project and specify which of JDK you have configured is used in the
>   current projects. Remember that JDKs are configured at IDE level, so
>   when you create another project, you won't need to add the same JDK
>   again.

reference : 
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html