# Locate JDK for intellij

Tags: java, java-8

I've been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263287/cant-locate-jdk-x64-in-intellijidea) article, but when I open the Libraries tab, the JDK doesn't show up. I know I have it because jGrasp is working just fine; plus, I just downloaded it again using a link I found inside intellij. Do I just need to save the jdk somewhere else? It was under *C:\Program Files\Java* until I downloaded it again using the intellij link, but now I don't see it anywhere. In any case, it wouldn't let me select the jdk I'd had saved there before (it was JDK 8u151).

Any advice would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE: I finally got this to work through a combination of following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241360/2981518) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263287/cant-locate-jdk-x64-in-intellijidea), and by re-downloading the jdk a couple times.

Comment: In your command prompt, do `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i`. This should give you the location of your java installation, which you can then use for setting up JDK in IntelliJ. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine).

Comment: I've looked at that article as well. when I type that into my command prompt, though, nothing happens. I have a Windows 10 computer, so I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: What does `java -version` print?

Comment: C:\>java -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then it isn't on the PATH

Comment: Java isn't setup in the `PATH` properly. Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241360/2981518).

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to re-download the jdk because I can't find it anywhere on my computer anymore, but when I went to do so, it said "Installation of JDK 8 Update 151 was not completed. Try to run installer again or consult the installation log file for more details:" and then it goes on to list where the log is.

Comment: I did that PATH thing though.

Comment: I'm guessing something went wrong in your JDK download. Maybe try it again - [JDK 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) or [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and then install.

Comment: Got it to work!!

Comment: Thanks everyone!